# separate mongodb and postgres datasources

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

We have a postgres data source in our spring app, we are considering using a separate mongodb database to be used a a datasyn for aggregations, is it possible to setup spring jpa to deal with 2 datasources of heterogenious drivers ?

Comment: Maybe `AbstractRoutingDataSource` will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can have all datasource you want. You need to have multiple `@Configuration` classes and for each, a datasource configuration with his own `TransactionManager`.

You need also to mark one datasource as `@Primary`

[Here](https://github.com/ValerioMC/vforge-cauldron/tree/master/src/main/java/io/vforge/cauldron/config) you can find a complete application example of two datasource configuration in a spring boot application